# In a video playback at the browser, can you explain the purpose of requestVideoFrameCallback event

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, browser

What is the requestVideoFrameCallback() event in Chrome, and how does it relate to frame decoding timestamps and projecting frames on the monitor? Additionally, could you explain how developers can access these timestamps from javascript?

Comment: Did you even search on Google before asking this question?

Comment: Yes, may be I am missing something.  I want to understand when this event is fired up. In this link [link](https://blog.tomayac.com/2020/05/15/the-requestvideoframecallback-api/),it says "which runs in the rendering steps when a new video frame  is sent to the compositor". What is the compositor. It says that also "The effective rate at which callbacks are run is the lesser rate between the video's rate and the browser's rate. This means a 25fps video playing in a browser that paints at 60Hz would fire callbacks at 25Hz.A 120fps video in that same 60Hz browser would fire callbacks at 60Hz."